# NestJS 5 GraphQL Error Query defined in resolvers, but not in schema

Tags: typescript, heroku, graphql, nestjs

I'm getting an error similar to the error described in [Query.products is defined in resolvers but not in schema](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50760443/5623385) but only when I push to Heroku. Here are the details:

```
// profile.graphql
type Profile {
  id: ID!
  version: String!
  // ...
}

type Query {
  profile(id: ID!): Profile
  profiles: [Profile]
}
```

```js
// profiles.resolver.ts
import { Args, Query, Resolver } from '@nestjs/graphql'
import { Profile } from './profile.entity'

@Resolver('Profile')
export class ProfileResolver {
  @Query()
  public async profile(@Args('id') id: number) {
    return await Profile.findOne(id)
  }

  @Query()
  public async profiles() {
    return await Profile.find()
  }
}
```

Locally, I can run `yarn start:dev` and it works great. The application starts successfully and I can query my GraphQL endpoint without a problem.

When I push this to Heroku, the application never starts up.

```
2019-04-03T15:42:38.102056+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `node dist/main.js`
2019-04-03T15:42:42.448420+00:00 app[web.1]: [Nest] 4   - 4/3/2019, 3:42:42 PM   [NestFactory] Starting Nest application...
2019-04-03T15:42:42.499150+00:00 app[web.1]: [Nest] 4   - 4/3/2019, 3:42:42 PM   [InstanceLoader] ConfigModule dependencies initialized +51ms
2019-04-03T15:42:42.499439+00:00 app[web.1]: [Nest] 4   - 4/3/2019, 3:42:42 PM   [InstanceLoader] TypeormConfigModule dependencies initialized +0ms
2019-04-03T15:42:42.499805+00:00 app[web.1]: [Nest] 4   - 4/3/2019, 3:42:42 PM   [InstanceLoader] TypeOrmModule dependencies initialized +0ms
2019-04-03T15:42:42.500251+00:00 app[web.1]: [Nest] 4   - 4/3/2019, 3:42:42 PM   [InstanceLoader] ApiModule dependencies initialized +1ms
2019-04-03T15:42:42.500726+00:00 app[web.1]: [Nest] 4   - 4/3/2019, 3:42:42 PM   [InstanceLoader] PassportModule dependencies initialized +0ms
2019-04-03T15:42:42.501201+00:00 app[web.1]: [Nest] 4   - 4/3/2019, 3:42:42 PM   [InstanceLoader] DataModule dependencies initialized +1ms
2019-04-03T15:42:42.501651+00:00 app[web.1]: [Nest] 4   - 4/3/2019, 3:42:42 PM   [InstanceLoader] GqlConfigModule dependencies initialized +0ms
2019-04-03T15:42:42.502039+00:00 app[web.1]: [Nest] 4   - 4/3/2019, 3:42:42 PM   [InstanceLoader] EntitiesModule dependencies initialized +0ms
2019-04-03T15:42:42.502411+00:00 app[web.1]: [Nest] 4   - 4/3/2019, 3:42:42 PM   [InstanceLoader] UsersModule dependencies initialized +0ms
2019-04-03T15:42:42.502819+00:00 app[web.1]: [Nest] 4   - 4/3/2019, 3:42:42 PM   [InstanceLoader] HelpersModule dependencies initialized +0ms
2019-04-03T15:42:42.503246+00:00 app[web.1]: [Nest] 4   - 4/3/2019, 3:42:42 PM   [InstanceLoader] ProfilesModule dependencies initialized +1ms
2019-04-03T15:42:42.503676+00:00 app[web.1]: [Nest] 4   - 4/3/2019, 3:42:42 PM   [InstanceLoader] ResourceTypesModule dependencies initialized +0ms
2019-04-03T15:42:42.504107+00:00 app[web.1]: [Nest] 4   - 4/3/2019, 3:42:42 PM   [InstanceLoader] SchemaMappingsModule dependencies initialized +1ms
2019-04-03T15:42:42.504580+00:00 app[web.1]: [Nest] 4   - 4/3/2019, 3:42:42 PM   [InstanceLoader] SearchReplaceValuesModule dependencies initialized +0ms
2019-04-03T15:42:42.505006+00:00 app[web.1]: [Nest] 4   - 4/3/2019, 3:42:42 PM   [InstanceLoader] XpathExpressionsModule dependencies initialized +0ms
2019-04-03T15:42:42.505581+00:00 app[web.1]: [Nest] 4   - 4/3/2019, 3:42:42 PM   [InstanceLoader] JwtModule dependencies initialized +1ms
2019-04-03T15:42:42.550301+00:00 app[web.1]: [Nest] 4   - 4/3/2019, 3:42:42 PM   [InstanceLoader] AppModule dependencies initialized +45ms
2019-04-03T15:42:42.553207+00:00 app[web.1]: [Nest] 4   - 4/3/2019, 3:42:42 PM   [InstanceLoader] GraphQLModule dependencies initialized +3ms
2019-04-03T15:42:42.553861+00:00 app[web.1]: [Nest] 4   - 4/3/2019, 3:42:42 PM   [InstanceLoader] AuthModule dependencies initialized +0ms
2019-04-03T15:42:42.674522+00:00 app[web.1]: query: SELECT * FROM "information_schema"."tables" WHERE "table_schema" = current_schema() AND "table_name" = 'migrations'
2019-04-03T15:42:42.690182+00:00 app[web.1]: query: SELECT * FROM "migrations" "migrations"
2019-04-03T15:42:42.693584+00:00 app[web.1]: No migrations are pending
2019-04-03T15:42:42.696083+00:00 app[web.1]: [Nest] 4   - 4/3/2019, 3:42:42 PM   [InstanceLoader] TypeOrmCoreModule dependencies initialized +142ms
2019-04-03T15:42:42.734620+00:00 app[web.1]: [Nest] 4   - 4/3/2019, 3:42:42 PM   [RoutesResolver] AppController {/}: +35ms
2019-04-03T15:42:42.735243+00:00 app[web.1]: [Nest] 4   - 4/3/2019, 3:42:42 PM   [RouterExplorer] Mapped {/, GET} route +4ms
2019-04-03T15:42:42.735665+00:00 app[web.1]: [Nest] 4   - 4/3/2019, 3:42:42 PM   [RoutesResolver] AuthController {/auth}: +0ms
2019-04-03T15:42:42.737212+00:00 app[web.1]: [Nest] 4   - 4/3/2019, 3:42:42 PM   [RouterExplorer] Mapped {/register, POST} route +2ms
2019-04-03T15:42:42.739125+00:00 app[web.1]: [Nest] 4   - 4/3/2019, 3:42:42 PM   [RouterExplorer] Mapped {/login, POST} route +0ms
2019-04-03T15:42:42.739137+00:00 app[web.1]: [Nest] 4   - 4/3/2019, 3:42:42 PM   [RouterExplorer] Mapped {/refresh, POST} route +0ms
2019-04-03T15:42:42.849522+00:00 app[web.1]: (node:4) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Query.profile defined in resolvers, but not in schema
```

**Why do I get the error in production and not in development?** What is happening that makes the GraphQL schema not register my `profile` query?

Comment: What happens when you run `yarn start` locally?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The difference between local and prod lends itself to Typescript. I found out that none of the `.graphql` files were being copied by Typescript so I used [`copyfiles`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/copyfiles) to solve the issue after my dist folder was created.